# apache2 does not write php output

Tags: php, python, apache, python-2.7, apache2

On Ubuntu 14 I have installed Apache2 with PHP 5.
I am trying to use php to run a python script and display the output in Apache.
To test I did a simple python script that just prints "Hello World" and calling it from a php file as below:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$command = escapeshellcmd("sudo /usr/bin/python      /script/provisioning/temp_script/test/test.py ");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

When I go in the browser and run the file nothing shows up. If I do a simple php file with echo "Smth" then the apache does display the result.

If I run the php file from the CLI as "php " the python script runs and I get the expected result.

What do I need to do so that apache2 will display the result ?

Best regards,
Vladimir

Comment: I'd think your apache user wouldn't have `sudo` permission.

Comment: Let's start with the basics. Have you looked in Apache's log files? That can tell you a lot about a "White Screen of Death".

Comment: The user account that Apache runs as (www) Should NEVER have access to sudo. **WOW what a hackers paradise that would make.** And besides that, sudo should/would be asking for a password anyway, which you are not able to enter when run like this

Comment: Hello, figured it out. I just needed to add permissions to the Apache user "www-data" to the PHP file. This solved it. Thank you very much for your suggestions